# list functions are not working.I don't know why but all the list functions are not working I tried re-installing python but nothing happens

Tags: python

If I do

```
l1=(5,6,4,8)
l1.sort()
print(l1)
```

the result is:

```
PS C:\code> python -u "c:\code\Rough&Notes\test.py"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\code\Rough&Notes\test.py", line 3, in <module>
    l1.sort()
AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'sort'
```

I tried this code in VS Code and Pycharm both but it didn't work in either.

Comment: The error message is trying to help you out. You have created a tuple (which is an immutable data type) which cannot be sorted. You want a list. Use `[...]` instead of `(...)` to create a list.

Answer (score 1):

you have to edit `l1=(5,6,4,8)` to `l1=[5,6,4,8]`

```
l1=[5,6,4,8]
l1.sort()
print(l1)
```

Comment: Using `l1=(5,6,4,8)` you get a tuple. Tuples can be used as parameters or as an index in an array, but function that are meant for lists usually don't work on them.